# Keycloak Keystore and Java Keystore with HTTPS -> redirect loop

Tags: docker, ssl, keycloak, shinyproxy

I run keycloak built with Docker and run into a strange Error. This is my Dockerfile for Keycloak. It use the LetsEncrypt certificate changed the .pem files to .crt and .key files, since the Keycloak keystore needs a tls.crt and a tls.key file.

```
docker run  -d \
 -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/tls.crt:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt \
 -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/tls.key:/etc/x509/https/tls.key \
 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=myadmin \
 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=mypassword \
 -p 8443:8443 jboss/keycloak
```

I run another docker container from the following file: Since I can not import multiple files in the Java Keystore I converted the .crt and .key into a .der file and also tried a .p12 file. Both did not work.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

COPY certificate.pfx $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/certificate.pfx

RUN \
    cd $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security \
    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.pfx -srcstorepass -changeit -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore cacerts -deststorepass changeit -deststoretype JKS

RUN mkdir -p /opt/shinyproxy/
RUN wget https://www.shinyproxy.io/downloads/shinyproxy-2.3.0.jar -O /opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar
COPY application.yml /opt/shinyproxy/application.yml

WORKDIR /opt/shinyproxy/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar"]
```

It gets started by the following command:

```
sudo docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net sp-example-net -p 5000:5000 shinyproxy-example
```

Nginx sits in front of the endpoints as a reverse proxy: This is how it is done:

```
location / {

        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;

       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_read_timeout 600s;

       proxy_redirect    off;
       proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
       proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


    }

    location /auth/ {

        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:8443;

       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_read_timeout 600s;

       proxy_redirect    off;
       proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
       proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
```

I guess there might be an issue with the Java Keystore where I copy the .der/.p12 files into, but maybe it´s also related to keycloak. These are my errors:

On the browser I see this:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

This shows up when starting the Application.

> 2019-12-22 17:14:06.033  WARN 1 --- [  XNIO-2 task-6]
>   a.a.ClientIdAndSecretCredentialsProvider : Client 'account' doesn't
>   have secret available 2019-12-22 17:14:06.050 ERROR 1 --- [  XNIO-2
>   task-6] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : failed to turn code
>   into token
>
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Can anyone help me how to correctly import the certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Very likely your Keycloak cert `/etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/tls.crt` doesn't contain full cert chain. It is very common issue for LE certs. Also ssllabs.com reports chain issue for `ds-gym.de` domain. Please fix cert (use fullchain pem cert format) and restart Keycloak.

At least this is one obvious problem in your setup.

Comment: I added the fullchaim.pem like this, is this correct? 
 -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt \
 -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/privkey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key \

Getting the other different error now :-(

17:22:56,513 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-5) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=authorization_code

Comment: @DataMastery `invalid_client_credentials` it is another issue - probably you have configured wrong client secret in the shinyproxy config file or OIDC client is not configured correctly

Comment: I guess it´s a similar error, here are my logs: 
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (that is the error from shinyproxy)
Anything wrong with the Dockerfile?? You already were so helpful :-)

Comment: @DataMastery Are you sure that chain issue was fixed? https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ds-gym.de still reports incomplete cert chain. It looks like nginx servers https://ds-gym.de/ so fullchain cert needs to be configured in the nginx conf.

Comment: Keycloak behind reverse proxy needs also special config. Add `-e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` config to Keycloak container.

Comment: I have got 4 certificates. cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem (which is cert.pem + chain.pem) and privkey.pem. In nginx it looks like this:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

Comment: So many nginx is correct?

this `-e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` helped a lot. Certificate was found. Now i´m finally here:
Client 'shinyoid' doesn't have secret available.
failed to turn code into token
status from server: 400

At least no more path errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204849/discussion-between-jan-garaj-and-data-mastery).

Comment: if anyone is interested: At the end it was a typo! The rest works fine. Jan Garaj helped me to find it :-)